# FTC Android Studio problems

Tags: java, android-studio, robotics

(This is for my FIRST team)
When attempting to compile my code, and to put the result on the Driver Station, after hitting the Play button there is a "Module Not Specified" error and the resulting code is not compiled and the Op Mode is subsequently not on the Driver Station. We are now using version 3.0 of Android Studio (previously an outdated version). In previous times, we did not have this error with a module. Is anyone capable of explaining the concept of a module and how to add one so this error stops? I myself am fairly new to software development using Android Studio. Though I do not believe the code is the error, I will provide it for the sake of context. Any help is appreciated :D

```
package org.firstinspires.ftc.teamcode;

import com.qualcomm.robotcore.eventloop.opmode.OpMode;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.eventloop.opmode.TeleOp;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.hardware.DcMotor;
import org.firstinspires.ftc.robotcore.external.Telemetry;

@TeleOp(name="AutoDrive", group="TankDrive")
public class AutoDrive extends OpMode 
{
    private DcMotor leftFrontMotor = null;
    private DcMotor leftBackMotor = null;
    private DcMotor rightFrontMotor = null;
    private DcMotor rightBackMotor = null;
    boolean sent;
    private int driveTime;
    public void init()
    {

        leftFrontMotor = hardwareMap.dcMotor.get("leftFront"); //Get motor objects, store them in corresponding reference variables
        rightFrontMotor = hardwareMap.dcMotor.get("rightFront");

        leftFrontMotor.setPower(0);
        rightFrontMotor.setPower(0);



        driveTime = 3000 // Robot will take 3 seconds with current weight to drive to safe zone
        Telemetry.addLine("Hardware variables successfully instantiated");
        sent = Telemetry.update();
    }

    public void start()
    {

        long limit = System.currentTimeMillis() + driveTime;

        while(System.currentTimeMillis() < limit) //drive in straight line for limit seconds
            drive();

        Telemetry.addLine("Stopping..");
        sent = Telemetry.update();
    }

    public void loop() {}

    public void stop() 
    {

        leftFrontMotor.setPower(0);
        rightFrontMotor.setPower(0);
        Telemetry.addLine("Robot successfully stopped.");
        sent = Telemetry.update();

    }
    private void drive()
    {
        leftFrontMotor.setPower(1);

        rightFrontMotor.setPower(1);

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the 'sent' variable? It doesn't seem like it does anything in particular.

Answer (score 3):

```
Telemetry.addLine("Hardware variables successfully instantiated");
sent = Telemetry.update();
```

Should be

```
telemetry.addLine("Hardware variables successfully instantiated");
sent = telemetry.update();
```

When lowercase, you are referencing the telemetry object in OpMode (which is what you want). The addLine and update methods are not static so you cannot call them through the class Telemetry.

Answer (score -1):

```
        leftFrontMotor = hardwareMap.dcMotor.get("leftFront"); //Get motor objects, store them in corresponding reference variables
    rightFrontMotor = hardwareMap.dcMotor.get("rightFront");
```

should be

```
        leftFrontMotor = hardwareMap.get(DcMotor.class, "leftFront"); //Get motor objects, store them in corresponding reference variables
        rightFrontMotor = hardwareMap.get(DcMotor.class, "rightFront");
```

Comment: This is incorrect and would result in a syntax error.

Comment: Well, now I see what's wrong and have edited the post. But it should be DcMotor anyway. DcMotor references the class name instead of an undefined variable named "dcMotor".

Comment: The HardwareMap class actually has a variable called dcMotor, which has a method get(String deviceName). The code you're suggesting is wrong will work correctly. However, the way you have it is the currently recommended way.

Comment: Oh ok. I didn't know that.